# implement Smart Lock Password on Firebase Login

Tags: android, google-api, kotlin, firebase-authentication, google-smartlockpasswords

I have been trying to implement Smart Locks on my Firebase Login Auth method, but I have to admit for the past two days, the google docs tripped me.

Could anyone give me a help?

This is my Auth login with Google

```
val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

    mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener { })
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build()

    loginGoogleBtn.setOnClickListener {
        val signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient)
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE)
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_SIGN_IN)
    }


}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    val currentUser = auth.currentUser
    updateUI(currentUser)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
        val result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data)
        if (result.isSuccess) {
            if (result.signInAccount != null) {
                val account = result.signInAccount!!
                val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.idToken, null)
                firebaseLogin(credential)
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("Error", "Could not signin google")
        }
    } else {
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by Smart Lock? Do you mean e.g. On-body detection, trusted places, trusted voices etc?

Comment: Hi. Sorry if I was unclear. I mean this https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/. The auto-login with a gmail, if the user has smart-lock activated

Comment: @TomAlabaster , do you know what it is?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the Firebase Auth UI code here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android. They have Smart Lock implemented.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot do you know where on my code I can implement what they provide? Which is this: startActivityForResult(
    AuthUI.getInstance()
        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
        .build(),
    RC_SIGN_IN);

Answer (score 0):

In your LoginActivity you can add this:

```
private val smartLockClient by lazy {
    Credentials.getClient(this)
}

private val firebaseAuth by lazy {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.login) // put a id "container" in the root ViewGroup

    // Run Google Smart Lock
    smartLock()
}

private fun smartLock() {
    container.visibility = View.GONE

    val credentialRequest = CredentialRequest.Builder()
            .setPasswordLoginSupported(true)
            .setIdTokenRequested(true)
            .setAccountTypes(IdentityProviders.GOOGLE, IdentityProviders.FACEBOOK)
            .build()
    smartLockClient.request(credentialRequest).addOnCompleteListener { task ->

        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            // See "Handle successful credential requests"
            val credential = task.result?.credential ?: return@addOnCompleteListener
            when (credential.accountType) {
                null -> {
                    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(credential.id, credential.password
                            ?: "")
                }
                IdentityProviders.GOOGLE -> {

                    GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                            .setAccountName(credential.id)
                            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                            .build()
                            .let { GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, it) }
                            .silentSignIn()
                            .addOnSuccessListener {
                                val authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(it.idToken, null)
                                firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential)
                                        .addOnSuccessListener { onSignInSuccess() }
                                        .addOnFailureListener { onSignInFailure() }
                            }
                            .addOnFailureListener { onSignInFailure() }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private onSignInSuccess(){
    // navigate to your main page or something else
}

private onSignInFailure(){
    // smart lock fail, so show the user the buttons "Sign in with Google", "Sign in with Email", "Sign in With Facebook", etc.
    container.visibility = VISIBLE
}
```